# Psycopg2 ThreadedConnectionPool instance collision

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have modified an existing dpOperations class to include ThreadedConnectionPool but I have a few concerns that my implementation is incorrect, below is the code:

```
class DBOperations():
    def __init__(self, host, dbname, user, password, port):
        self.conn = None
        self.cur = None
        self.row_count = None
        self.results = None
        self.pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
            MIN_CONNECTIONS,
            MAX_CONNECTIONS,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            database=dbname,
            port=port
        )

    # get connection from pool
    def get_conn(self):
        self.conn = self.pool.getconn()

    # get cursor
    def get_cur(self):
        if not self.conn:
            raise psycopg2.errors.ConnectionFailure("unable to get connection to database")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)

    # close connection from pool
    def close(self):
        self.cur = self.cur.close()
        self.conn = self.pool.putconn(self.conn, close=True)
    
    # wrapper provides inits pool connection + release after each query 
    def get_pool_connection(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.conn:
                try:
                    self.get_conn()
                    self.get_cur()
                    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                finally:
                    self.close()

            else:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @get_pool_connection
    def execute(self, query, params=()):
        try:
            result = self.cur.execute(query, params)
            logger.info(self.cur.query)
            self.conn.commit()
        except Exception as exc:
            logger.debug(str(exc))
            self.conn.rollback()
        else:
            # fetch results for class storage
            try:
                self.row_count = self.cur.rowcount
                self.results = self.cur.fetchall()
            except:
                pass
            return result

        try:
            result = self.cur.execute(query, params)
            self.conn.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e,exc_info=True)
            logger.exception(e)
            return None
        else:
            try:
                self.row_count = self.cur.rowcount
                self.results = self.cur.fetchall()
            except:
                pass
            return result
        
    def fetchall(self):
        result = self.results \
            if self.results else []
        self.results = None
        return result

    def fetchone(self):
        result = self.results[0] \
            if self.results else None
        self.results = None
        return result
```

The wrapper opens/closes the connection for every db query and returns the connection. Before I implemented the pool, the db object was created with 1 connection and passed to all of the classes to use. I would like to optimize the threading solution but I am worried about a collision happening with synchronous queries using the same class instance as below.

Example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
    def query(self):
        db.execute("select * from table1;")
        return db.fetchone()
class B: 
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
    def query(self):
        db.execute("select * from table2;")
        return db.fetchone()


db = DBOperations(
    host=HOST,
    dbname=DATABASE,
    user=USER,
    password=PASSWORD,
    port=PORT
    )

a = A(db)
b = B(db)

#assume this happens at the same time
a.query()
b.query()
```

Assuming the a.query and b.query operations happen in a multi-threaded environment at the same time, would this cause a conflict? Also, is there a implementation to avoid this without having to re-write the query() functions for classes A and B? This is an example and I would like to avoid creating a massive code-overhaul. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do not shared the same instance of `DBOperations` with `A` and `B`. In a multi-threaded environment `self.cur = self.conn.cursor` could cause issues, as the cursor would be overwritten by another thread (assuming `.query()` running in parallel).

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, I thought that would be an issue.. trying to find a solution without doing a major code-overhaul, might be unavoidable... thank you